# Absolute link to relative link with VBA Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, fso

I'm trying to link my reports but unfortunately it doesn't work I need the relative path and not the absolute path so that the user can access the reports. the problem I manage to write the link in .\ but the program should always update something before .\ so that in the end I get the main path plus the relative path so that the user can access the reports no matter where they are located.

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    ' Setzen Sie den HostFolder auf das Basisverzeichnis, wo Ihre Datenbank und Berichte liegen
    ' Passen Sie den Pfad entsprechend an
    HostFolder = "C:\Users\fouas\Music"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
End Sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next SubFolder
    
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Überprüfe, ob die Datei eine PDF-Datei ist
        If LCase(Right(File.Name, 4)) = ".pdf" Then
            ' Hier die Logik einfügen, um Autor, Titel, Datum und Link aus dem Dateinamen zu extrahieren
            Dim pdfData As Variant
            pdfData = Split(File.Name, "_") ' Annahme: Dateiname hat Format "BerichtNr_Schlusswort_Datum_Titel_Autor.pdf"
            
            If UBound(pdfData) >= 4 Then
                Dim pdfLink As String
                pdfLink = File.Path ' Pfad zur PDF-Datei
                
                ' Extrahiere die Daten aus pdfData
                Dim BerichtNr As String
                Dim Schlusswort As String
                Dim Datum As String
                Dim Titel As String
                Dim Autor As String
                BerichtNr = pdfData(0)
                Schlusswort = pdfData(1)
                Datum = Replace(pdfData(2), ".", "/")
                Autor = pdfData(3)
                Titel = pdfData(4)
                
                ' Hier den Code einfügen, um die relative Verknüpfung zu erstellen
                ' Der relative Pfad ist der Pfad von HostFolder zum aktuellen Bericht
                Dim relativePDFLink As String
                relativePDFLink = ".\" & Replace(pdfLink, HostFolder & "\", "")
                
                ' Öffne die Access-Datenbank
                Dim db As DAO.Database
                Set db = OpenDatabase("C:\Test§\Tab1_test.accdb") ' Passe den Pfad zur Access-Datenbank an

                ' Öffne die Tabelle in der Access-Datenbank
                Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
                Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tabelle1", dbOpenDynaset) ' Passe den Namen deiner Access-Tabelle an

                ' Füge die Daten in die Access-Tabelle ein
                rs.AddNew
                rs("BerichteNr").Value = BerichtNr
                rs("Schlusswort").Value = Schlusswort
                rs("Datum").Value = Datum
                rs("Titel").Value = Titel
                rs("Autor").Value = Autor
                rs("PDFLink").Value = relativePDFLink ' Verknüpfung ist jetzt relativ
                rs.Update

                ' Schließe die Recordset und die Datenbank
                rs.Close
                Set rs = Nothing
                db.Close
                Set db = Nothing
            End If
        End If
    Next File
End Sub
```

Comment: "no matter where they are located" - what does that mean, why would there be different locations? What is "main path" and what is "relative path" - relative to what?

Answer (score 0):

So, guessing you Hostfolder remains the same. It is best to store the name of the pdf sepperatly :

Get the name of the pdf and store this in your database.

```
Public Function GetFileName(ByVal path As String) As String
    'Test : ? GetFileName("C:\path\to\your\file.pdf")
    '
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fso As Object
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Extract the file name from the full path
    fileName = fso.GetFileName(path)
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Extract the file name from the full path
    fileName = fso.GetFileName(path)
    
    GetFileName = fileName

End Function
```

Get the relative path of your end user.

```
Public Function GetFileName(ByVal path As String)
    'Test : ? GetFileName("C:\path\to\your\file.pdf")
    '
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim fso As Object
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Extract the file name from the full path
    fileName = fso.GetFileName(path)
    
    ' Create a FileSystemObject
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Extract the file name from the full path
    fileName = fso.GetFileName(path)
    
    GetFileName = fileName

End Function
```

Now combine this if you want to open the file.

```
Public Function OpenFile(ByVal strFileFolder As String, ByVal strFileName As String) As String
    
    'Test : ? OpenFile(GetRelativePath(),GetFileName("C:\Users\MZENNER\Documents\toDeleteAsap.pdf"))
    'Test : ? OpenFile(GetRelativePath(),"toDeleteAsap.pdf")
    '
    Dim filePath As String
    
    filePath = strFileFolder & strFileName
    Shell "explorer.exe """ & filePath & """", vbNormalFocus
    
End Function
```